# How to set common property across all schema in Mongoose?

Tags: mongoose

In my project I have multiple mongoose schema. The requirement is to add new property across all the schema. I want to avoid copy paste same thing across all schema. Looking for an alternative.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose: extending schemas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317284/mongoose-extending-schemas)

Answer (score 3):

Achieved the above requirement, sharing common property across the schema, (extending the schema). Following are the steps,

Created an object with all common property, example,

```
var baseProperty = {
    deleted     :   Boolean
    createdBy   :   String,
    updatedBy   :   String,
    createdAt   :   Date,
    updatedAt   :   Date,
};
```

then used in different schema in following way,

```
/** SCHEMA 1 **/ 
var userSchema = new Schema({
    name    :   String,
    mobile  :   String,
    email   :   String,
}, {});
userSchema.add(baseProperty);      // Injecting common property in schema
mongoose.model("User", userSchema); 


/** SCHEMA 2 **/
var addressSchema = new Schema({
    city    :   String,
    state   :   String,
    country   : String,
}, {});
addressSchema.add(baseProperty);  // Injecting common property in schema
mongoose.model("Address", addressSchema);
```

Now the above schema is ready with injected property, for CRUD operations.

Comment: Forget to mention, the mongoose version am using is **4.7.5**