# How to extend a userShema in meanjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meanjs

I want to create two differents users for my meanjs app, a candidate and recruiter, they will have similar and different fields, so how can I extend the user Schema, to avoid duplicating code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose: extending schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317284/mongoose-extending-schemas)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to use mongoose discriminators. With discriminator you will have 3 schemas, a user Base schema where you will write all the similar code, and then recruiter and candidate schemas that will implement discriminators key. Here's some info about it:

[Mongoose discriminators](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html)

[Guide to Mongoose Discriminators](http://thecodebarbarian.com/2015/07/24/guide-to-mongoose-discriminators)

Comment: I thought about this solution too, Thank you for confirming