# how to use base schema to child schema in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have parent schema which is common field for all the child schema. How to extend parent to child schema?

**parent schema**

```
const BaseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  eventId: {
    type: dataTypes.ObjectId,
    required: false
  },
  eventType: {
    type: dataTypes.String
  },
  eventSource: {
    type: dataTypes.String
  },
 })
```

**child schema**

```
const ChildSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  eventId: {
    type: dataTypes.ObjectId,
    required: false
  },
  eventType: {
    type: dataTypes.String
  },
  eventSource: {
    type: dataTypes.String
  },
age : {
    type: dataTypes.String
  },
name : {
    type: dataTypes.String
  },
place : {
    type: dataTypes.String
  },
 })
```

The question is eventId,eventType,eventSource is common for all the schema so tires to create one common for above fields. I creadted that schema as BaseSchema. Is possible to use like this? How to extend the base to child?

Comment: what to do you want exactly? could you please elaborate more

Comment: I added more content to the question can you please check

Comment: This post might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317284/mongoose-extending-schemas

Comment: You can try mongoose [clone()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/schema.html#schema_Schema-clone) and there is a npm you can try [mongoose-schema-clone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-schema-clone)

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/schema.html#schema_Schema-add